# Which memory locations to use for variable storage

Tags: c, memory

Higher level languages such as javascript don't give the programmer a
choice as to where variables are stored.  But C does.  My question is: 
are there any guidelines as to where to store variables, eg dependent
on size, usage, etc.

As far as I understand, there are three possible locations to store
data (excluding code segment used for actual code):

1. DATA segment
2. Stack
3. Heap

So transient small data items should be stored on the stack?

What about data items which must be shared between functions.  These
items could be stored on the heap or in the data segment.  How do you
decide which to choose?

Comment: C typically doesn't give you those choices, you probably are assuming some compiler-specific extensions. The most important tool is scope; all that can be local should be local.

Comment: C will not let you specify where you want the variable to go. No compiler will.

All local variables will go on the stack, all literals will end up in DATA.

Comment: Global variables usually ends up in DATA/BSS section, unless you specify otherwise using compiler specific extensions.

Comment: @Shark Nonsense. There is no "stack" nor "DATA" in C. You're referring to x86 terms, and C wasn't designed solely for x86. C is a third-generation programming language. If C were *higher level* (sic) than Javascript, then Javascript would have to be first or second generation (eg. machine code and assembly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking through the wrong end of the telescope.  You don't specify particular memory segments in which to store a variable (particularly since the very concept of a "memory segment" is *highly* platform-dependent).

In C code, you decide a variable's *lifetime*, *visibility*, and *modifiability* based on what makes sense for the code, and based on that the compiler will generate the machine code to store the object in the appropriate segment (if applicable)

For example, any variables declared at file scope (outside of any function) or with the keyword `static` will have *static storage duration*, meaning they are allocated at program startup and held until the program terminates; these objects may be allocated in a data segment or bss segment.  Variables declared within a function or block without the `static` keyword have *automatic storage duration*, and are (typically) allocated on the stack.

String literals and other compile-time constant objects are often (but not always!) allocated in a readonly segment.  Numeric literals like `3.14159` and character constants like `'A'` are not *objects*, and do not (typically) have memory allocated for them; rather, those values are embedded directly in the machine code instructions.

The heap is reserved for *dynamic storage*, and *variables* as such are not stored there; instead, you use a library call like `malloc` to grab a chunk of the heap at runtime, and assign the resulting pointer value to a variable allocated as described above.  The *variable* will live in either the stack or a data segment, while the memory it *points to* lives on the heap.

*Ideally*, functions should communicate solely through parameters, return values, and exceptions (where applicable); functions should not share data through an external variable (i.e., a global).  Function parameters are usually allocated on the stack, although some platforms may pass parameters via registers.

Answer (score 2):

You should prefer local/stack variables to global or heap variables when those variables are small, used often and in a relatively small/limited scope. That will give the compiler more opportunities to optimize the code using them as it'll know they aren't going to change between function calls unless you pass around pointers to them.

Also, the stack is usually relatively small and allocating large structures or arrays on it may lead to stack overflows, especially so in recursive code.

Another thing to consider is the use of global variables in multithreaded programs. You want to minimize chances of race conditions and one strategy for that is maiking functions thread-safe and re-enterant by not using any global resources in them directly (if `malloc()` is thread-safe, if `errno` is per-thread, etc you can use them, of course).

Btw, using local variables instead of global variables also improves code readability as the variables are located close to the place where they're used and you can quickly find out their type and where and how they're used.

Other than that, if your code is correct, there shouldn't be much practical difference between making variables local or global or in the heap (of course, `malloc()` can fail and you should remember about it:).

Answer (score 0):

C only allows you to specify where data is stored indirectly... via the scope of the variable and/or allocation. i.e., a local variable to a function is typically a stack variable unless it is declared static in which case it will likely be DATA/BSS. Variables created dynamically via new/malloc will typically be heap.

However, there's no guarantee of any of that... only the implication of it.

That said, the one thing that is guaranteed to be a bad idea is to declare large local variables in functions... common source of strange errors and stack overflows. Very large arrays and structures are best suited to dynamic allocation and keep the pointers in local/global as required.